# How to determine the correct time using quadratic functions if there are multiple "correct" roots exist in a 3D system?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, time, vectors

Time can be calculated from a modified kinematics quadratic formula using the initial velocity, displacement, and acceleration. However, the acceleration vector isn't limited to 1 axis.

When applying a quadratic kinematics equation you get 2 roots. However, since acceleration isn't along 1 axis there are 3 quadratic equations for determining X, Y, and Z, meaning there are 6 roots. I know one out of the six roots is correct, but I don't know how to calculate that step.

The other values aren't necessarily negative either so they can't be written off as incorrect.

I used the determinate equation to find values that equaled 0, and still had multiple answers.

My question is how to calculate which time is the correct answer if there are multiple "correct" roots to 3 quadratic equations.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "the correct answer". I mean, suppose I just asked you "quick, $x$ is an even number, what's the correct answer?" There's absolutely no way to answer that without more detail. Which of the six roots you want depends on what you're using it for.

Comment: The time must satisfy all three equations. They have to have a common root.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the problem you are solving? If we can see the equations and the motion being described, then we can give better advice.

Answer (score 2):

For example, if I throw a ball up at speed $v$ from height $H$, it follows the trajectory:

$$ h(t) = H + vt - \frac 1 2 g t^2 $$

so it hits the ground when:

$$ -\frac 1 2 g t^2 + vt + H = 0 $$

or:

$$ t_0 = \frac{v\pm\sqrt{v^2+2gH}}{2g}$$

We are going to choose:

$$ t_+ = \frac{v + \sqrt{v^2+2gH}}{2g} > 0$$

as our answer because it occurs after we start the experiment at $t=0$.

The negative root:

$$ t_- = \frac{v - \sqrt{v^2+2gH}}{2g} < 0$$

occurs before we start the experiment. It represents the solution running the experiment backwards in time (or at least continuing it to earlier times, with the same kinematics).

Note that if $H<0$, meaning we start below ground level, and:

$$ v \lt \sqrt{2g|H|}$$

the solutions are imaginary, meaning the speed is too small to reach the height $h=0$.

That is just one example, but in general, the various "unwanted" roots do tell you something about the problem.